# On which SE site may I ask a question about online collections of moving JavaScript imagery?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm interested in learning how to create simple interactive and dynamic visualizations with JavaScript. For instance, I'd like to make an image of a digital clock that starts running as soon as the user hoovers their mouse over the image.

In order to learn about these things, I think it would be useful for me if there'd be a large, open-source online repository of such dynamic images, including the code. However, I haven't been able to find such a website thus far.

Therefore, I'd like to ask a question about this on one of the Stack Exchange website. I'm not sure though which one would be most appropriate for such a question -- if any.

Comment: maybe [softwarerecs.se]? be sure to check their faq though

Comment: @corn I doubt they'd like it.

Comment: It might be on topic on OpenData but I am not a user there so you might want to ask on their meta first.

Comment: It depends on, what you really want. If you are looking for a javascript image manipulation software, visit https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com . If you want to learn the basics of the javascript development, then you can not ask it, because it is not a single question and a single answer. However, if you want to learn JS development, then start by googling for "how to start to learn javascript development" or similar, and follow what you find.

Comment: You will have a tremendous amount of questions - and these questions will be already on-topic on https://stackoverflow.com , https://superuser.com or on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 5):

Recommendation type questions are off topic on much of SE, and we don't really have a site where website or learning material repository recommendations are on topic.

There's no real fit for your question.